# jQuery jCorner Plugin is not working - What am I missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to use the jCorner plugin for jQuery, but falling down at the majority of the hurdles. See http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/ for the plugin, but I do not understand the concepts behind jQuery.

The code is at http://ghostworksinc.com/new, then hit view source to see the hash I've made.

The code is compiled with a sinatra app running at Heroku.

The div I want to corner-ify has an id of cornered and a class of cornerdiv, and given that I know no javascript whatsoever I'm stabbing in the dark.

Does anybody have any working code for using jCorner?

Thanks,
Luke

$(function(){
        $('div.cornerdiv').each(function() {
            $(this).corner();
        });
    });

Comment: Posting the Javascript and HTML code here will help.

Comment: Hi, it wont let me post since Bears will eat you added in another link :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Just click the "edit" button.

Comment: As it was a new acount, it only let me add one link, but apparently i've just earned the "Student" badge. Thanks for your help, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi you're including the corner plugin before you're including jquery.

try switching them

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>
```

Comment: To elaborate, the `<script>` tag that imports jQuery needs to be above any `<script>` tags that import jQuery plugins.

Comment: +1 - The corner plugin relies on jQuery in order to function. When it loads, there is no jQuery yet.

Comment: You can also shorten your code to - $('.cornerdiv').corner();